# Converting Web Applications into Android

Tags: android, webview

I have developed  5 web applications(GAMES) in which i have developed in PHP and Mysql.
Now i want them to convert into Mobile Applications i.e., the 5 games can be played in android mobile

Now my doubt is can I use android WebView and load them or should I develop them from scratch in android.
Please suggest me how to develop them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use WebView witch is not best solution with HTML 5 and some CSS3 app, or you can create native app from beginning by create web Service Restful or what ever working with Json object like facebook and g-mail app did.

native app is faster and better however if you don't need high quality app use webView and design your website for mobile using HTML 5 and CSS3 then simply just by upload website content to WebView congratulations you have android app as same as to IOS and Windows Phone.

there is a lot online tools helps to convert your website to android app like :

1-http://www.bmobilized.com/

check this http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/convert-websites-for-mobile-devices/

i assume if you know how to use **HTML5 and CSS3** you create Manual i mean with out using online tools `web Design for mobile` will be better and never ever tested those online tools so check them

difference between native app and web app.

check out : http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-native-apps/

Answer (score 0):

I'm Sure that MoSync Will help you.
you can write Cross-platform programs with MoSync.